# Unity3d Callback for Android Facebook Ad Attribution by UserID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Cannot find where to hook a callback to find out which of my users have installed the mobile app off of a facebook ad campaign:

I've:

- Gone through facebook unity sdk docs and not found how to get attribution from install (FB.PublishInstall() or FB.ActivateApp()
- Queried Insights and could only get aggregated daily mobile installs {app-id}/insights/application_mobile_app_installs

want to track which users are coming in from facebook campaigns

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell if a user who uses your application did so as a result of a Facebook Ad Campaign.

If you need to do cross channel measurement or LTV calculation, you will need to work with one of [Facebook's Mobile Measurement Partners](http://www.facebook-pmdcenter.com/category/mobile).